# AJAX Request sends back same thing on mobile but not desktop

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a page set up to request information from a page 10 times when the page loads. On Desktop, it sends back and displays 10 different users. However, on Mobile, it returns the same exact user information.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var i = 0;
   while(i < 10)
     {
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "./func/gather.func.php",
                   data: {}, // serializes the form's elements.
                   success: function(data)
                   {
                    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('.posts').append('<div class="post" id="post-'+ response[0].streamID_gather +'"><div class="title-card"><div class="avatar-sec"><img src="'+ response[0].avatarSrc +'" class="avatar" ref="Avatar" /></div><div class="name-card"><span class="display-name">'+ response[0].display_name +'</span><span class="handle">@'+ response[0].name +' '+ response[0].followsYou +'</span></div><div class="action"><span class="like" id="like">'+ response[0].amt +' <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div></div><div class="body-card">'+ response[0].p_message +'</div><div class="footer"><div class="follow-button '+ response[0].follow +'" id="'+ response[0].streamID_gather +'">'+ response[0].follow +'</div></div></div>');
                    }
                 });
        i++;
     }  
   });
```

**Here is the Desktop View when page is loaded**

[image: Desktop View]

**Here is the Mobile View when page is loaded**

[image: Mobile view]

Comment: Isn't it because of cache? Please try to attach some random string to the url. For e.g. set url as `"./func/gather.func.php?g=" + Math.random()`. Or you can add `cache: false` in `$.ajax()` params.

Comment: Is this exactly the code you are using? `data: {}` means there is no POST data sent to the server, so unless there is some strange behaviour on the server side, it should be expected to always return the same result. And on a general note: Can't you retrieve 10 results at once and loop through them instead of doing 10 ajax calls?